# Reduce Number of Requests

Tags: frontend, performance, optimization

I want to reduce the number of requests to optimize a Magento website. Merged JS and CSS files but it didnt work for me.

Comment: what you have try for that?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it didn't work for me" - no effect at all?

Comment: First, you need to put Magento 2 in production mode to use Merged JS, and also try JS Bundling.

Answer (score 5):

what you can try:

1. CSS sprites to merge many images into one.
2. inline small CSS/JS files right into HTML.
3. use base64 data for small images https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/
4. CDN or domain sharding https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/domain-sharding-2/
5. enable HTTP2

Taken from [34 steps](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento) to speed up magento 2 and 1

Answer (score 4):

You have to use lazy load functionality for homepage, It is presumed there are number of products you showing on homepage and all product images have separate request.

You have to go with this : 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_gazillion.html

By this images will load on scroll and only one request fire for all catalog images.

Defiantly this will make sense in your requests.